# Ещё раз про основу предложения

Tags: синтаксис

В связи с вопросом про "модель гроба". Вот предложение **Какие же это слова?** Если здесь подлежащее местоимение *это*, а сказуемое существительное *слова*, то определение *какие же* относится к сказуемому?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Какие же это слова?" никак не соотносится с "это модель гроба". Здесь ЭТО - частица в вопросительном предложении для усиления вопросительного местоимения. Нужно уметь различать омонимичные части речи.

Слова-подлежащее. Какие же это - сказуемое.

Comment: >Нужно уметь различать омонимичные части речи.  
  
И как это сделать? Научите.  ))))
Ну вот хотя бы на этих двух примерах. Пока что - замкнутый круг. Структуру предложения Вы выводите из необходимости различения омонимичных слов, а сами ити различия - из априорно заданной структуры предложения.

Comment: Не из структуры предложения, а из роли этой части речи. Изначально ЭТО - указательная частица: Москва - это столица. Частица служит для указания на предмет, признак, действие. Служит, помимо этого, для подчёркивания, выделения члена предложения, перед которым находится: это наивные только верят тому, что говорят по телевизору; для указания на мысль или слово предшествующего предложения: Вчера сосед заходил.- Это Петров что ли?; для усиления вопросит. местоимения или наречия в вопросит. предложении или смягчения категоричности вопроса: О чём это вы? Куда это вы собрались?

Comment: Однако частицы имеют тесные  связи с другими классами слов - в них  присутствуют элементы значений местоименных слов,например, это(указ. мест. ЭТОТ в ср.р.), если обозначает предмет,явление, человека как объект истолкования, то, о чём  говорится в предшествующем предложении. Тогда это местоимение и может быть подлежащим или определением.

Comment: Простите, пожалуйста, не могу более участвовать в дискуссии, очень некогда, готовлюсь к отъезду дня на 4,попробовала отнести вас к сайту, но не нашла, и времени нет искать. Забежала сюда на минуту, больше не могу.

Answer (score 0):

> ... то определение "какие же" относится к сказуемому?

Это не противоречит грамматике ни вообще, ни в рамках заявленного подхода.

И коль скоро мы договорились, что именная часть речи в рамках исповедуемого подхода может быть сказуемым, но нет ничего страшного, что и определение (если это оно) относится к сказуемому.

Меня более забавляет сам факт такой интерпретации. Мне так и не сказали, это что-то новомодное или теперь так детей учат. 
И даже если оно так, то как быть с "Какие же это были слова"? По той же схеме подучается, что "были слова" - сказуемое, а вот "определение" относится к одной из его частей, но в то же время к сказуемому в целом не относится. Вот где бардак-то...

Comment: Я думала, что ответа Людмилы достаточно.

Comment: Я не вижу здесь ответа Людмилы.